# How to improve single insert performance in oracle

Tags: oracle, performance, oracle11g, sql-insert

In my business case, I need insert one row and can't use batch insert  . So I want to know what the throughput can made by Oracle. I try these ways:

#### Effective way

- I use multi-thread, each thread owns one connection to insert data
- I use ssd to store oracle datafile

#### Ineffective way

- I use multi table to store data in one schema
- I use table partition
- I use multi schema to store data
- Turn up data file block size
- Use append hint in insert SQL

In the end the best TPS is 1w/s+

#### Other:

- Oracle 11g
- Single insert data size 1k
- CPU i7, 64GB memory

Comment: With an insert size of 1k you don't need anything special unless there are extraordinary circumstances not explained in your question. I can definitely say (1) don't up the block size, (2) don't use multiple schemas if you ever hope to query the data, (3) don't thread your client code if you think Oracle is the bottleneck, and (4) the `append` hint doesn't apply here. And as a manager I suggest: *focus on your app, not on a single insert*. Do a vanilla `INSERT` and move on. Nobody will thank you if the insert's slightly faster but the app is delivered late and the `INSERT` logic is a hot mess.

Comment: Thank a lot for your advisor.  but  In my case， I use oracle  as a eventstore in  my framework (related to  CQRS).   So only insert and select will  happen,  I need to try the best to improve the insert performance .

Comment: What is "single insert"? Inserting 1 row using `insert ... values`?

Answer (score 1):

Oracle is highly optimized for anything from one row inserts to batches of hundreds of rows.  You do not mention whether you are having performance problems with this one row insert nor how long the insert takes.  For such a simple operation, you don't need to worry about any of those details.  If you have thousands of web-based users inserting one row into a table every minute, no problem.  If you are committing your work at the appropriate time, and you don't have a huge number of indexes, a single row insert should not take more than a few milliseconds.

In SQL*Plus try the commands

```
set autotrace on explain statistics
set timing on
```

and run your insert statement.

Edit your question to include the results of the explain plan.  And be sure to indent the results 4 spaces.